# How to control sampling in Opentracing

Tags: sample-rate, opentracing

I am new to opentracing and was trying it out. 
Wanted to know is there a way to control sample rate and yes then how? 
thanks,
Sandy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends entirely upon which implementation you use. For example, both Brave and Jaeger support sampling, and I would expect most other implementations do as well. That said, the OpenTracing spec does not cover sampling at this time-- it only handles the API for how to create traces, and doesn't cover what happens to traces after they created.

Comment: Ok so if i am using Brave Tracer how can I configure it? Can you share sample Brave Tracer init code?

Comment: Got it. There is a brave.sampler.Sampler which can be used when building Brave Tracer.